# WPF - control keyboard navigation in TreeView

Tags: .net, wpf, treeview, keyboard-navigation

I have a problem with the keyboard navigation in my treeview.
I'm implementing a 3 column table. Each element in the first column consists of 3 columns:
An Icon, a textBlock and an expander. If the element's property "hasItems" is false, the expander is hidden. My problem is that I can't use the up and down arrows to navigate up and down the tree. I've tried to set the expander "IsTabStop" property to true but this doesn't give me the required result. 
It feels like the expander takes the focus: The up and down arrows only get the focus on and off the expander (when I remove the expander the navigation acts as expected).

This is some kind of pseudo code, just to explain my hirerchy:

```
<ScrollViewer >

        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeRootInstance}">
        <TreeView.Resources>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate">
                    <Border >
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image  Grid.Column="0"/>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1"  />
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"
                                      Grid.Column="2"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"
                                      ClickMode="Press"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>


                <GridViewColumnCollection x:Key="gvcc">
                    <GridViewColumn  CellTemplate="{StaticResource CellTemplate}" >
                        <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock   Text="First Column" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock   Text="Second Column" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn >
                        <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="Third Column"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>

                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridViewColumnCollection>



<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Columns="{StaticResource gvcc}"
                                                                ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeHeaderStyle}"
                                                                Margin="0"
                                                                DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Thanks,
Li

Comment: It's hard to tell how you're using your `GridViewColumnCollection`, are you using a `ListView` inside the `ItemTemplate` for the `TreeView`? In that case it feels like the `ListViewItems` are getting the focus. Setting `Focusable="False"` in the right place should fix it, at `ItemContainerStyle` for `ListViewItem` for example, but as I said, it's hard to tell

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's sort of a legacy code, and I'm new at WPF, so I'm still trying to figure out what's going on there... But could you pls tell me why setting the expander's "focusable" to false wouldn't work?  (Then I can just expand the expander manually by catching some other event...)

Comment: Pls note that the first column of GridViewColumnCollection uses the cellTemplate that was defined earlier in the code

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. I tried to reproduce your problem here but it's a little hard since I'm not sure what the rest of it looks like. Do you use a `ListView` somewhere?

Comment: Many thanks for your help... As I said, I'm new in WPF and I feel really lost there ... (It isn't the easiest thing to debug, is it?). Anyway, I'm thinking about setting the expander's Focusable to false, then catching some event (maybe "KeyDown" or something) and then if the key is Enter - manually "expand" or "collapse" the expander... Do you think that it can work?

Comment: You'll still be able to click the Expander `Button` to expand/collapse even if `Focusable` is set to false so you won't need to handle any events to make it work. Hard to say if `Focusable="False"` on the expander will solve your problem, try it out and report back here

Comment: I've tried, and the navigation seems great but I can't press the expander button (nothing works - none of the arrows, not enter nor "plus")... besides - isn't the idea of setting focusable = false to deny the user the ability to press the control? 
btw - I found another piece of code that didn't seem important earlier, I'll edit the original question

Comment: @user429400, did u get the solution?

Comment: not quite :( I've implemented some workaround (setting the expander's "focusable" to false and then catching a "keydown" event, checking if enter was pressed and then expand/collapse manually) but I'm sure there's nicer way...